# How do I delete secret subkeys correctly?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I tried to use `gpg --delete-secret-keys` to delete some revoked subkeys but ended up accidentally deleting my primary key instead.

I was able to reproduce my mistake with the following commands:

```
$ gpg --batch --passphrase '' --quick-generate-key 'test key' rsa4096 cert 0
gpg: key 0xA52099E0E7EB77A5 marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: revocation certificate stored as '~/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/D7D79C32883EA862C586881DA52099E0E7EB77A5.rev'
$ gpg --batch --passphrase '' --quick-add-key D7D79C32883EA862C586881DA52099E0E7EB77A5 rsa4096 sign 0
$ gpg --list-keys
pub   rsa4096/0xA52099E0E7EB77A5 2019-04-10 [C]
      Key fingerprint = D7D7 9C32 883E A862 C586  881D A520 99E0 E7EB 77A5
uid                   [ultimate] test key
sub   rsa4096/0x20AA2F4F7A28CD01 2019-04-10 [S]
      Key fingerprint = 9CAE 802D A78E 4624 BD8F  88FE 20AA 2F4F 7A28 CD01
$ gpg --delete-secret-keys 9CAE802DA78E4624BD8F88FE20AA2F4F7A28CD01

sec  rsa4096/0xA52099E0E7EB77A5 2019-04-10 test key

Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N)
```

Even though I specified the *subkey* by fingerprint, `gpg` asks me to confirm the deletion of the *primary key*.

The [manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html) states:

> `--delete-secret-keys name`
>
> Remove `key` from the secret keyring.
>   In batch mode the `key` must be specified by fingerprint.
>   The option `--yes` can be used to advice gpg-agent not to request a confirmation.
>   This extra pre-caution is done because gpg can’t be sure that the secret key
>   (as controlled by gpg-agent) is only used for the given OpenPGP public key.

I tried using batch mode as well:

```
$ gpg --batch --yes --delete-secret-keys 9CAE802DA78E4624BD8F88FE20AA2F4F7A28CD01
$ gpg --list-secret-keys
# Empty output.
# Primary key has been deleted.
```

I specified the *subkey* by fingerprint but `gpg` interpreted the command as if I had specified my *primary key* instead.

What is the correct way to do this? Did I understand it wrong?

Comment: Thanks! This is a great question. It is very odd behavior how GPG removes all the subkeys.

Comment: @xer0x You're welcome. It should be fixed in newer versions of GPG!

Comment: Unfortunately, I just came across this behaviour today with gpg 2.4.3. It deleted the primary secret key (and all subkeys). It's not fixed, @MatheusMoreira. Looks like we need to end the key id with `!`, which is quite unintuitive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained by [Peter Lebbing](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2019-April/061839.html) and [Daniel Kahn Gillmor](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2019-April/061840.html) on the [mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2019-April/061828.html), the answer for `gpg 2.2.15` is to ask `gpg-agent` to delete the secret subkey.

```
# Obtain the keygrip of the subkey you want to delete.
$ gpg --with-keygrip --list-secret-keys "$YOUR_FINGERRINT"

# Ask gpg-agent to delete the key for you.
# There should be a graphical confirmation prompt.
$ gpg-connect-agent "delete_key $KEYGRIP" /bye
```

`gpg-agent` is the program that actually manages the secret keys.
Each secret key corresponds to a file named `"$GNUPGHOME"/private-keys-v1.d/"$KEYGRIP".key`.
In order to delete a secret subkey, the user must obtain its keygrip and then ask `gpg-agent` to delete it.

Documentation for the `delete_key` command:

```
$ gpg-connect-agent 'help delete_key' /bye
# DELETE_KEY [--force|--stub-only] <hexstring_with_keygrip>
#
# Delete a secret key from the key store.  If --force is used
# and a loopback pinentry is allowed, the agent will not ask
# the user for confirmation.  If --stub-only is used the key will
# only be deleted if it is a reference to a token.
OK
```

Apparently, there is no way to tell `gpg` to ask `gpg-agent` to delete a secret subkey on the user's behalf.
[An issue](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4457) has been opened about this.

Comment: Note that this doesn't necessarily ensure that the key cannot be forensically recovered.

Answer (score 7):

As of `gpg 2.2.19` (maybe earlier versions too) `--delete-secret-keys` (and `--delete-keys`, `--delete-secret-and-public-key`) works as expected and deletes only a subkey if the fingerprint of the subkey suffixed by an exclamation mark is given.

From the man:

> --delete-keys name
>
> Remove key from the public keyring. In batch mode either --yes is required or the key must be specified by fingerprint. This is a safeguard against  accidental
> deletion  of  multiple  keys.   If the exclamation mark syntax is used with the fingerprint of a subkey only that subkey is deleted; if the exclamation mark is
> used with the fingerprint of the primary key the entire public key is deleted.

**Example**

```
$ gpg --list-keys --with-subkey-fingerprints test
pub   rsa4096 2022-01-18 [SC] [expires: 2024-01-18]
      9D41A3F0A1A83972A9CC66FA4D37F47018B8C1B9
uid           [ultimate] test key
sub   rsa2048 2022-01-18 [E]
      BC147C4DF05144EDF10E9C76B0A369B86587C7CF
sub   rsa2048 2022-01-18 [S]
      D4BF3307C15BFBB146D62A4D8E43F32CE9A59953
           
$ gpg --delete-secret-and-public-keys BC147C4DF05144EDF10E9C76B0A369B86587C7CF!
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19; Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


sec  rsa2048/B0A369B86587C7CF 2022-01-18 test key

Note: Only the secret part of the shown subkey will be deleted.

Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N) y
This is a secret key! - really delete? (y/N) y

sub  rsa2048/B0A369B86587C7CF 2022-01-18 test key

Note: Only the shown public subkey will be deleted.

Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N) y

$ gpg --list-keys --with-subkey-fingerprints test
pub   rsa4096 2022-01-18 [SC] [expires: 2024-01-18]
      9D41A3F0A1A83972A9CC66FA4D37F47018B8C1B9
uid           [ultimate] test key
sub   rsa2048 2022-01-18 [S]
      D4BF3307C15BFBB146D62A4D8E43F32CE9A59953
```

Comment: Indeed! [An issue was opened about this](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4457) and it was eventually resolved. Newer versions now behave as expected.